# Ошибка при перехвате файлов

Tags: c#, wpf

Создаю WPF-приложение. Требуется что бы при перехвате файлов в определенной папке в окне менялось содержимое. Но выскакивает ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа
> "System.InvalidOperationException" в
> PresentationCore.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Вызывающим
> потоком должен быть STA, поскольку
> этого требуют большинство компонентов
> UI.

Имеется класс MyPanel, который в свою очередь состоит из полей класса MyField. У класса MyPanel есть метод AddField(MyField field).

```
public class MyPanel
{
   public MyPanel() { ... }
   public void AddField(MyField field) { ... }
}

public class MyField
{
   public MyField() //Ошибка при перехвате файла
   { ... }
}

public class Watcher
{
   public Watcher(string path)
   {
      FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
      watcher.Created += watcher_Сreated;
      watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   }
   public MyPanel panel { get; set; }
   private void watcher_Сreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
   {
      MyField field = new MyField();
      panel.AddField(field);
   ...
```

Вот после предпоследней строчки при переходе на конструктор MyField - ошибка.
Помогите решить эту проблему? Самому понять ошибку знаний видимо не хватает...

Comment: Всё создание интерфейсных элементов должно происходить в основном STA-потоке. Событие, как я понимаю, обрабатывается совсем не в нем. Видимо, придется орагнизовать в главном потоке polling, который будет просматривать общий для всех тредов список созданных файлов и при обнаружении нового создавать интерфейсные элементы.

Comment: А можно выполнить связывание и обойтись без диспетчеризации. Пусть этим wpf  и занимается. В классе MyPanel сделать свойство ObservableCollection<string>  и добавлять новые файлы туда. Само поле связать с представлением (ListView или что другое) через binding. Все работает в разных потоках и не мешает друг другу.

Comment: Хм... Как то ни разу не приходилось работать ни с одним из предложенных вариантов. Конечно, меня больше привлекает, то что проще

Comment: @krupennikov: А какое у вас разделение на View, VM и модель? От этого зависит правильный ответ.

Watcher — это явная модель, а вот что такое MyField и MyPanel?

Comment: Оба класса наследуются от Grid. MyPanel состоит TextBlock с заголовком и StackPanel с экземплярами MyField. А MyField состоит из TextBlock (имя файла), MyTextBox (наследуемый от TextBox для ввода комментария). В общем при перехвате файла надо чтобы в MyPanel либо добавлялся еще один MyField, либо удалялся, переименовывался. Вроде ничего сложного, а столкнулся с тем, с чем ни разу не сталкивался

Comment: @krupennikov: тогда уже неправильно. У вас модель напрямую меняет View, так не взлетит.

Comment: @VladD, и ObservableCollection не поможет?

Comment: @krupennikov: При неправильной архитектуре можно затыкать дыры там и тут, но проблемы будут появляться всегда. ObservableCollection — это техническая деталь реализации, а вопрос в правильной организации программы.

---
Кроме того, в WPF не принято наследоваться от контролов, это же не WinForms. Но это мелочь по сравнению с.

Comment: @VladD, у меня в MyTextBox при вводе выскакивает Popup со списком слов для организации более быстрого ввода. Типа как в WinForm это сделано. В DoubleTextBox можно вводить только числа. Такие наследия тоже не рекомендуются? Неужели будут проблемы? Прогу то делаю для личных целей, для помощи в моей основной работе.

Comment: @krupennikov: TextBox с popup'ом не является TextBox'ом, так как реализует другую семантику, значит, наследование — неверный механизм. Поэтому вам нужен UserControl, который содержит TextBox, Popup и логику их связи.

То, что именно можно вводить в TextBox, должно определяться, опять-таки, навесным валидатором (например, Binding/Converter).

Разве то, что вы делаете программу для личных целей, оправдывает вольности в архитектуре? Вам решать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте-ка перепишем архитектуру на MVVM.

**Модель**. Это та штука, которая общается с внешним миром. И может быть многопоточной. Модель **ничего** не знает про остальные уровни.

```
public class Watcher : IDisposable
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher;

    public Watcher(string path)
    {
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher.Created += OnChanged;
        watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
    }

    void OnChanged(object o, FileSystemEventArgs args)
    {
        if (Changed != null)
            Changed(this, args);
    }

    public event FileSystemEventHandler Changed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        watcher.Changed -= OnChanged;
        watcher.Deleted -= OnChanged;
        watcher.Created -= OnChanged;
        watcher.Dispose();
    }

    // дополнительная логика, если нужна.
}
```

Отлично, теперь **VM** и бизнес-логика. Этот уровень руководит моделями, запускает и останавливает их, приводит всю информацию в главный поток, и представляет её в виде, удобном для View. Но этот уровень ничего не знает о View.

```
class FileEntry : DependencyObject
{
    // dependency property стандартного вида
    public string Path
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(PathProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(PathProperty, value); } 
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                  "Path", typeof(string), typeof(FileEntry));

    // ну и другие, если нужно
}

// все методы и поля, кроме отмеченных, используются из главного потока
class FileList : DependencyObject
{
    public FileList()
    {
        Files = new ObservableCollection<FileEntry>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FileEntry> Files { get; private set; }

    private Model.Watcher watcher;

    public void StartWatchFolder(string path)
    {
        RemoveWatcher();
        SetWatcher(new Model.Watcher(path));
    }

    void RemoveWatcher()
    {
        if (watcher != null)
            watcher.Change -= OnChangeExternal;
        watcher = null;
    }

    void SetWatcher(Model.Watcher watcher)
    {
        this.watcher = watcher;
        if (watcher == null)
            return;
        watcher.Change += OnChangeExternal;
    }

    // будет вызываться в произвольном потоке
    void OnChangeExternal(object o, FileSystemEventArgs args)
    {
        Redirect(() => OnChange((Model.Watcher)o, args));
    }

    void OnChange(Model.Watcher w, FileSystemEventArgs args)
    {
        if (w != this.watcher)
            return; // устаревшее сообщение
        var entry = new FileEntry() { Path = args.Path };
        Files.Add(entry);
    }

    // будет вызываться в произвольном потоке
    void Redirect(Action a)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(a);
    }
}
```

Ну и **View**, наконец. Этот уровень ничего не знает о моделях, и общается с VM лишь посредством `DataContext`'а и команд (`ICommand`). Совершенно тривиально:

```
<ResourceDictrionary
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Program.VM"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Program.View"
    ...>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FileEntry}">
        <view:FileEntryView/>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictrionary>

<UserControl x:Class="Program.View.FileEntryView" ...> <!-- бывший MyField -->
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text={Binding Path}/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Comment"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Class="Program.View.FileListView" ...> <!-- бывший MyPanel -->
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource={Binding Files}/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Прога для личных целей не оправдывает, конечно. Но когда не существует нужной программы для работы, приходится делать самому. Соответственно и учиться приходиться чему то новому в программировании... Спасибо за ответ, попробую переделать проект согласно Вашему ответу

Comment: Ну никак не получается, прога перехватывает файлы, но в ListView ничего не добавляется. Уже голову сломал экспериментами и поиском инфы. Гляньте проект у себя, где я ошибся
http://krupennikov.ucoz.ru/load/0-0-0-31-20
В проге указан перехват в C:\Test

Comment: @krupennikov: Подправил, вот результат: http://rghost.ru/private/52907774/8ba7d306d5277100635d73839b9f8165

Смотрите, в чём проблема: вы не вполне правильно передаёте DataContext. View не должен пытаться сам себе создать DataContext, он должен получить его от parent view. У вас View кладёт в ресурсы свой личный экземпляр VM, и устанавливает на него DataContext. Но эта VM — не та VM, которая нужна! VM должна быть создана и запущена один раз, а View лишь только ссылается на неё.

Comment: @krupennikov: Я сделал так, что главная VM создаётся в App.xaml.cs и убрал StartupURI из App.xaml (т.к. главное окно не должно создаваться без DataContext'а).

Вроде всё работает. (Да, ещё я изменил путь.)

Comment: @krupennikov: Ещё немного добавил красоты: http://rghost.ru/private/52908730/87cd3e10bf787fd0aebd24a7be982430

Comment: @VladD, спасибо огромное. Все работает. Теперь буду разбирать этот код подробнее, чтобы полностью понять принцип работы

Comment: @krupennikov: пожалуйста! Если что, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте сделать так:
MyPanel - это, насколько я понял, юзер-контрол или окно. Добавляем свойство Files

```
public class MyPanel
{
   public MyPanel() 
   {
      Files = new ObservableCollection<string>();
      listBox.ItemsSource = Files;
      ...
   }
   public ObservableCollection<string> Files { get; private set; }
}
```

Заполнение:

```
private void watcher_Сreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
   {
      panel.Files.Add(.....FileName);
   ...
   }
```

Конечно, строки - это для примера. Можно закидывать и другие объекты, а в разметке прописать шаблоны их отображения, чтоб они по-разному выводились.

Comment: Судя по описанию на MSDN классная вещь этот ObservableCollection. Спасибо огромное, вечером обязательно попробую. Это штука мне много где пригодиться в моей проге...

Comment: @Pleshkov Ivan, не работает. Та же самая ошибка